# Can't access AWS RDS database even though CIDR/IP added in security group

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, rds, aws-security-group

I have created a db instance (sql server ex) in my AWS account and now trying to access it via MS SQL Server Management Studio or via Visual Studio Server Explorer, but i can't, i get the errors like below:

[image]

[image]

I have added my ip address in inbound under security group as well:
[image]

Comment: Is your RDS instance "publicly accessible" and in a public subnet?

Comment: Notice: your second and third rules are allowing anyone access. Delete those two rules. Verify that your home router security setting is not blocking port 1433. To verify turn off the router's firewall temporarily so that you can test.

Comment: You're not adding `,1433` to the hostname somewhere by chance are you?  That's an odd way for the error message to show a port number.

Comment: @MattHouser thanks a lot. I created a new db instance with public accessibility and could connect it fine. Subnets are coming as default from my default VPC. The db instance that i was trying to connect earlier was created privately i think, but i had played around it and i  believe i had changed it to be publicly accessible, but still hadn't had a chance to connect. Unfortunately it is deleted now, so i can't try with the same old instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am aware of those, they were they on purpose to test. That wasn't a firewall problem but i believe like Matt said it was a "publicly accessible" problem

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i was indeed adding the port number, that is an optional parameter.

Comment: Maybe this is a Windows thing, but the typical convention is for port numbers to be preceded by `:`, not `,`.  Does anything change if you remove it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i have seen them both in use. But anyways i checked all 3 combinations (no port ";" ","), none worked. You can check for "," 
 usage here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

Answer (score 0):

I Tried all the above steps but didn't work. Even though, i have selected 'Publicly Accessible' while using visual studio, it didnt reflect in the aws console. So, the below steps worked for me. Please try this.

**Note:-** this is only for my testing/learning purposes. So, i made it publicly accessible. You might not enable publicly accessible if there is a security issue. If you are testing/using for learning purposes, you can follow the below approach.

Make sure your port is publicly accessible .Else you will not be able to connect.

To enable the public accesss, please follow the below steps.

1. Select the db instance --> click Modify

[image: Modify instance]

2. Scroll to connectivity Section, expand 'Additional configuration' section --> select 'Publicly Accessible'--> Scroll to bottom --> select update. (as shown below).
   [image]

3. Your db instance will be in modifying state and after 2-3 minutes it will be available. Now, give it a try to connect again and you will be able to connect now.